# java.io.IOException: open failed: EBUSY (Device or resource busy) in android

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard

I am creating a file in SD Card and storing image file in it, by using default camera.
That works fine.

But from 2 days i am getting an Exception of

```
`12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063): java.io.IOException: open failed: EBUSY (Device or resource busy)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:946)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1011)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at tv.caseguard.swipe.fragment.CameraPhoto.setImageUri(CameraPhoto.java:414)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at tv.caseguard.swipe.fragment.CameraPhoto.dispatchTakePhotoIntent(CameraPhoto.java:380)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at tv.caseguard.swipe.fragment.CameraPhoto.onClick(CameraPhoto.java:295)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EBUSY (Device or resource busy)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
12-25 11:50:59.328: W/System.err(5063):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
12-25 11:50:59.338: W/System.err(5063):     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
12-25 11:50:59.338: W/System.err(5063):     ... 15 more
`
```

My code part

```
try {
        _imageFileName = "Image_"+_timeStamp;
        _image = File.createTempFile(_imageFileName,".png", fileImage);
        imgUri = Uri.fromFile(_image);
        _imagePath = _image.getAbsolutePath(); // _video is file to send and _videoPath is string path
        System.out.println("Image path on sd card=" + _imagePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Insufficient information. Add your code snippet.

Comment: @VicJordan Have a look again please

Comment: @ShoebAhmedSiddique Restart your Device. May be some other resources used the same file and that app or resources still open...

Comment: @VicJordan Logs added. Please do something in my favor

Answer (score -3):

It's too late, but might solve problem of others.
There is already a answer in SO. I didn't face any problem like you, so didn't try this out.

Visit the link
[open failed: EBUSY (Device or resource busy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539657/open-failed-ebusy-device-or-resource-busy)

Here is the code given in the link

```
final File to = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + System.currentTimeMillis());
file.renameTo(to);
to.delete();
```